# Configuring TFS - Advanced wizard

Tags: sql, tfs

Perhaps this was asked before but I can't find a whole lot on this, so I would appreciate some help.

Our architecture is as follows: Win 7 desktop on a domain with VS 2010. MS Sql server R2 on Win Server 2008 R2 Ent; SharePoint 2007 on Win 2003; SharePoint 2010 on Win 2008 R2 Ent; Visual Sourcesafe on yet another separate Win Server 2008 R2 Ent server. On this server I have just installed TFS and was running Advanced Config Wizard.

As I'm new to TFS all my selected options are based on intuition and perhaps common sense but Reporting Services and SharePoint aren't working. With reporting services after I add my sql server name (and I've tried IP address and dns name) neither the Report Server URL nor Report Manager URL is populated. (Note: What do I need reporting services for anyway?)

So I've opted not to use reporting services, which as I said, I don't know what is the benefit of it.

Next, in the SharePoint configuration, I wanted to use the existing SharePoint farm which is installed on a separate servers. Testing the Site and Administration URLs would throw an error: "The following site could not be accessed. ... Either ... not installed the Team Foundation Server Extensions, or Firewall... "

I suspect it is not the firewall so then the TFS Extensions. Having search that topic as well seems to point back to the TFS's configuration, so I'm a completely at a loss.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Risho
/posted from a smartphone since employer blocks this site/

Edited: I was looking at this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd631915.aspx but I don't have the options listed in the step-by-step solution. TFS Admin Console has this: Top tear - server name, below is Application Tear then Proxy Server, build Configuration and Logs. Expanding Application Tear shows Team Project Collections, SharePoint Web Applications, Reporting, and Lab Management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure the SharePoint extensions on [each SharePoint machine you wish to connect to TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462861%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#TFSExtensions). Install TFS on whichever SharePoint machine (or both, if you plan to use both). In the configuration wizard, you should have the option to configure SharePoint Extensions. Once done, you should be able to re-run the readiness checks in the Advanced Wizard on your Application Tier machine.

Comment: Thanks Russ for the input. Since my post I've made some progress but still no cigar. Here where I'm at: On the SharePoint server which is a separate server from where TFS lives, I have successfully configured the extensions and was able to grant acceess to my web application that I had to manually create: creted a web application - we have weird naming conventions so the sharepoint app is at the root of the server on port 80 http://00xxx-sp-020/ then I've creted a site collection http://00xxx-sp-020/apps.tfs which now has several errors displayed stating TF262600: (to continue...)

Comment: (continued..)  This SharePoint site was created using a site definition that requires data from Team Foundation Server." Other error states: "This site doesn't have a default Team Foundation Server instance. You can explicitly select a Team Foundation Server."

Comment: Looks like you should try the recommendations in [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2451685), and perhaps you need to manually hook the portal to a project, per [this blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2010/04/09/how-to-set-the-default-team-project-for-a-sharepoint-site.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this. The process has been painful but educational. The main issues seemed to have been our highly secure environment. Presently on the sharepoint I have a site collection based on the "agile" template and am able to connect to the TFS via the Team Web Access webpage dialog popup which sees a "DefaultCollection" but "There are no accessible team projects in the collection..." - On the TFS server in the Team Explorer adding a new team project was sucessfull.

Comment: Can you verify that you created the project in the same collection you to which you are connected, and that the Admin Console shows that there is a team project in that (enabled/successfully created) collection?